# WordProcessingML shapes problem 

Tags: wordprocessingml

I am currently working on exporting information from browser to word document. I am having information which contains colors and shapes. Now when I export them using wordprocessingML I am able to export text that are highlighted in colors. But I am also having certain text in browser that are encapsulated with circles ad box. I found that using VML we can render shapes. But I want the shapes to be in the specified x-axis and y-axis, so that it renders the text properly. Is there is any way to specify co-ordinates in shapes using keywords like "this.x", "this.y". Something similar to this to render the shapes on the text. I am not sure whether I am clear. Would like to discuss more about this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that solution for this problem. We can use "auto" keyword which can be used to find the relative position of the shapes in the worddocument according to the flow of the page. Now my question when I passed margin-left:auto, margin-top;auto, I was able to display the shapes in the right dimension. But I have also included text inside the text attribute which I want the shapes to be overlapped. I am getting shapes aside the text, not wrapping the text. Does anyone know the solution, I can try it. I find it really interesting to work on wordml.